# Present view controller using Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have followed a tutorial to add In App Purchases to my app. There are 2 views:

1. Button to 'Buy item'
2. Screen comes up that allows user to select product

I have added the code completely fine but in the tutorial they were using XIB files but I am using Storyboard. My code for the 'Buy item' button looks something like this:

```
- (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {

    _purchaseController = [[PurchasedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:nil];

    _purchaseController.productID = @"com.myapp";

    [self presentViewController:_purchaseController animated:YES completion:NULL];

    [_purchaseController getProductID:self];

}
```

The issue I have is that when the button is clicked, a black screen appears, but I want PurchasedViewController to show

Do I need to change something?

EDIT:

Using edited code but getting error as attached:

```
- (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {

        PurchasedViewController *purchaseContr = (PurchasedViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];
        //menu is only an example
        purchaseContr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:purchaseContr animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `[PurchasedViewController getProductID:]` do?

Comment: it gets the Product ID from the first view controller

Comment: What does the line `_purchaseController.productID = @"com.myapp";` do then?

Comment: in my code i wrote wrong name of viewController, check my answer now

Comment: Better, but still crashing. Check my screenshot

Comment: in storyboard there is a viewController with storyboard ID: menu ?

Answer (score 19):

With a storyboard you should give an Identifier like in the picture:
tap on your viewController and in 'identity inspector'

[image]

in this example Custom Class should be: `PurchasedViewController`

and this is the code:

```
 - (IBAction)PurchaseItem:(id)sender {
     PurchasedViewController *purchaseContr = (PurchasedViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];
     //menu is only an example
     purchaseContr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
     [self presentViewController:purchaseContr animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, where do I add that code in the context of my code?

Comment: Im getting an error on this line '    _purchaseController *purchaseContr = (_purchaseController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];'  saying Missing '[' at start of message sending expression

Comment: Also in your code, you have eliminated the _purchaseController.productID = @"com.myapp"; element which I think is key?

Comment: @Omar i wrote the code for transition from viewController A to viewController B with storyboard, you can add your code to this, for the error: are you sure to write this code correctly?

Comment: I copy and pasted Exactly as you wrote it - is there something i should change?

Comment: @Omar your identity inspector is like my photos?

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't make a difference anyway if Im getting code errors

Comment: @Omar yes i know, anyway make sure you've copied ';' or '='

Comment: Yes, have copied exactly as you presented bro

Comment: ok try to clean project shift+cmd+K, if this does not solve, copy your code in your question

Comment: Basically, I took what you pasted and copied that into my project. I didn't add any other code or change anything else     _purchaseController *purchaseContr = (_purchaseController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];
    //menu is only an example
    purchaseContr.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:purchaseContr animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Omar ok.. I seem to see that it's all right, have you tried to clean the project? edit your question and add this code with the relative error

Comment: I have updated my question with the code im using you suggested

Comment: Thank you, I am trying it now

Comment: It didn't seem to work, Ive updated my question with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_purchaseController = [[PurchasedViewController alloc] init];

_purchaseController.productID = @"com.myapp";        
/* 1. Add the new VC as a child VC */
[self addChildViewController:_purchaseController];

/* 2. Add new view to source view */
[self.view addSubview:_purchaseController.view];

 /* 3. Inform 'didMoveToParentViewController' to newly added view controller */
[_purchaseController  didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[_purchaseController getProductID:self];
```

Comment: didn't get what u r saying can you explain more "code doent do anything to button" mean