# IOS navigate to new view but get a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, presentviewcontroller

I have navigate to a new class with view by the below table view delegate method but I get a black screen returned.

```
#import "NewClass.h"

- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"MainStoryboard" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NewClass *new = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"newDetail"];
    new.array = localArray;
    [self presentViewController: new animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

I have NSLog the array on the new class there and the data is received in the new class, all the storyboard name, identifier tag are correct placed, but I don't know why I still getting a black screen, could anyone help me point out what is the error cause there?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665020/present-view-controller-using-storyboards

Comment: Please try setting newView's background color.

Comment: calling `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:...` creates a new instance of the storyboard. This won't give you access to the same instances that are actually loaded.

Comment: @Hemang "Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard resource file." [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:)

Comment: @Hemang i were set the NewClass as the first initialised view but it's not the problem of the color

Comment: Try NewClass *new = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController] as you said you has set the NewClass as the first initialised view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    NewClass * new = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newDetail"];
new.array = localArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:new animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you change the bundle to nil mean it won't receive any data in the new class and the Main is depend on the storyboard you named for the file

Comment: where you read this "bundle to nil mean it won't receive any data in the new class and the Main is depend on the storyboard you named for the file" firstly check my code

Comment: your code is wrong why you don't want to admit that you are wrong?

Comment: It's work when I using [self.navigationController pushViewController:new animated:YES];

Comment: the same thing i answered but u r not ready to accept it and downvote it

Comment: Not me down vote , u see my point is very low i am unable to down vote anything

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
ViewController *new = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"newDetail"];
```

And make sure the id of your view controller is set to newDetail on storyboard

Comment: NewClass is the imported class name, it's not a variable type

Comment: Is NewClass a child of UIViewController?

Comment: #import "NewClass.h"

Comment: @ interface NewClass

@ property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;

@ end

Comment: @interface NewClass: UIViewController , your new class should extend UIViewController